# Mailenable API AJAX Calls

Tags: api, mail-server

I am trying to understand how the MailEnable API works.
So far, I could only look at the AJAX documentation and got the LOGIN command work. It's like:

```
AJAXRequest('LOGIN','Username='user'&Password='pass', false);
```

That command returns an xml string like

```
<BASEELEMENT SCHEMA="VALUE" METHOD="LOGIN"><RETURNVALUE>1</RETURNVALUE></BASEELEMENT>
```

That working well, anything else than the LOGIN command (For example LOG-OFF or LIST-MESSAGES) gives me a timeout error like

```
<BASEELEMENT SCHEMA="TIMEOUT" METHOD="LOGOUT"></BASEELEMENT>
```

The commands I am using for LOG-OFF and LIST-MESSAGES are these and they both give me the below error.

```
AJAXRequest('LIST-MESSAGES','Folder=/Inbox', false);
AJAXRequest('LOG-OFF','ID=', false);
```

I am using the example files from [that](http://www.mailenable.com/developers/ajax_examples.zip) link. I just can't understand if I am missing something, or these examples and documentations are not up to date or has issues or smth?

Thanks!

(I couldn't find "mailenable" tag to tag this question. It's a pity that noone has tagged mailenable before in stackoverflow, mailenable forum is like a grave :S)

Comment: Did you find any answer for this till date?

Comment: No, mate. I gave up that a long time ago...

Comment: Though I tried the same thing long ago and could not find any solution. I designed my own http system for mail enable finally. But after coming across this post, thought you might have found the solution for this. Mail Enable documentation feels like outdated. Any ways if you want any further help I can post here my own http system.

Comment: Your suggestion is tempting :) Why don't you post your solution? May be I will start working on that after a long year :D

Answer (score 2):

Ok as per comments I am posting a self written Mail Api for MailEnable

```
Imports System
Imports System.Web
Imports MailEnable.Administration
Imports QueryStringModule
Imports System.Xml

Public Class MailApi : Implements IHttpHandler

Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property

Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    Dim doc As XmlDocument = GetXmlToShow(context)

    context.Response.ContentType = "test/xml"

    context.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF32 
    context.Response.Expires = -1
    context.Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(True)

    doc.Save(context.Response.Output)

End Sub

Private Function GetXmlToShow(context As HttpContext) As XmlDocument
    Dim Result As String = ""
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument

    Try
        Dim query As String = QueryStringModule.Decrypt(context.Request.QueryString("val").Replace(" ", "+"))

        Dim PostOffice As String = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query).Get("PostOffice")
        Dim Domain As String = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query).Get("Domain")
        Dim Username As String = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query).Get("Username")
        Dim Password As String = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query).Get("Password")
        Dim MailBoxQuota As Integer = CInt(Val(HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query).Get("MailBoxQuota")))
        If MailBoxQuota = 0 Then
            MailBoxQuota = 102400
        End If

        Dim act As String = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query).Get("Action")

        Select Case act
            Case "Create"
                Result = fnCreateMailAccount(Username, PostOffice)
            Case "Delete"

            Case "Update"

            Case "GetAll"
                Result = fnGetAll(Username, PostOffice)
            Case "GetToday"

            Case "GetFromTo"

            Case "GetUnread"
                Result=fnGetUnread(Username,PostOffice)
            Case "GetRead"

            Case "GetUnreadCount"
                Result = fnGetUnreadCount(Username, PostOffice)
            Case "GetTotalCount"
                Result = fnGetTotalCount(Username, PostOffice)
            Case Else
                Result = "<result status=""Err""><reason>Invaid action!</reason></result>"
        End Select

        doc.LoadXml(Result)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Result = "<result status=""Err""><reason>" + ex.Message + "</reason></result>"
        doc.LoadXml(Result)
    End Try
    Return doc 
End Function

Private Function fnGetUnread(Username As String, Postoffice As String) As String
    Dim XMLFile As String = ""
    Try
        If Len(Username) <= 0 Or Len(Postoffice) <= 0 Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("Invalid Parameters!")
        Else
            Dim oMailbox As New MailEnable.Administration.Mailbox
            oMailbox.Postoffice = Postoffice
            oMailbox.MailboxName = Username
            oMailbox.Status = 1

            If oMailbox.GetMailbox() = 1 Then
                Dim APIResult As Long
                Dim oStore As New MailEnable.Store
                APIResult = oStore.StoreFolder_Open(Postoffice, Username, "\Inbox", 0, 1)
                If oStore.StoreFolder_FindFirstItem() = 1 Then
                    Do
                        If oStore.StoreItem_GetProperty("PR_ME_READ").ToString = "0" Or oStore.StoreItem_GetProperty("PR_ME_READ").ToString = "" Then

                            Dim WrapperStart As String = "<message>"

                            Dim ItemId As String = "<itemid>" + oStore.StoreItem_GetProperty("ME_ITEM_ID").ToString + "</itemid>"
                            Dim MessageDate As String = "<dated>" + Left(oStore.StoreItem_GetProperty("PR_ME_MESSAGEDATE").ToString, 10) + " " + Right(oStore.StoreItem_GetProperty("PR_ME_MESSAGEDATE").ToString, 8) + "</dated>"
                            Dim Attachments As String = "<attachments>" + oStore.StoreItem_GetProperty("PR_ME_ATTACHMENTS").ToString + "</attachments>"
                            Dim From As String = "<from>" + oStore.StoreItem_GetProperty("PR_ME_FROM").ToString.Replace("<", """").Replace(">", """") + "</from>"
                            Dim Subject As String = "<subject>" + oStore.StoreItem_GetProperty("PR_SUBJECT").Replace("<", """").Replace(">", """").ToString + "</subject>"
                            Dim Size As String = "<size>" + oStore.StoreItem_GetProperty("PR_ME_SIZE").ToString + "</size>"
                            Dim Status As String = "<status>" + oStore.StoreItem_GetProperty("PR_ME_FLAGSTATUS").ToString + "</status>"

                            Dim WrapperEnd As String = "</message>"

                            XMLFile = XMLFile + WrapperStart +ItemId + MessageDate + Attachments + From + Subject + Size + Status + WrapperEnd
                        End If
                    Loop While (oStore.StoreFolder_FindNextItem() = 1)
                    XMLFile = "<messages>" + XMLFile + "</messages>"
                End If
                APIResult = oStore.StoreFolder_FindClose()
                APIResult = oStore.StoreFolder_Close()
            Else
                Throw New ArgumentException("Invalid Mailbox!")
            End If
        End If
        XMLFile = "<result status=""Success"">" + XMLFile + "</result>"
    Catch ex As Exception
        XMLFile = "<result status=""Err""><reason>" + ex.Message + "</reason></result>"
    End Try
    Return XMLFile
End Function

Private Function fnGetAll(Username As String, Postoffice As String) As String
    Dim XMLFile As String = ""
    Try
        If Len(Username) <= 0 Or Len(Postoffice) <= 0 Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("Invalid Parameters!")
        Else
            Dim oMailbox As New MailEnable.Administration.Mailbox
            oMailbox.Postoffice = Postoffice
            oMailbox.MailboxName = Username
            oMailbox.Status = 1

            If oMailbox.GetMailbox() = 1 Then
                Dim APIResult As Long
                Dim oStore As New MailEnable.Store
                APIResult = oStore.StoreFolder_Open(Postoffice, Username, "\Sent Items", 0, 1)
                If oStore.StoreFolder_FindFirstItem() = 1 Then
                    Do
                        Dim WrapperStart As String = "<message>"

                        Dim ItemId As String="<itemid>"+oStore.StoreItem_GetProperty("ME_ITEM_ID").ToString +"</itemid>"
                        Dim MessageDate As String = "<dated>" + Left(oStore.StoreItem_GetProperty("PR_ME_MESSAGEDATE").ToString, 10) + " " + Right(oStore.StoreItem_GetProperty("PR_ME_MESSAGEDATE").ToString, 8) + "</dated>"
                        Dim Attachments As String = "<attachments>" + oStore.StoreItem_GetProperty("PR_ME_ATTACHMENTS").ToString + "</attachments>"
                        Dim From As String = "<from>" + oStore.StoreItem_GetProperty("PR_ME_FROM").ToString.Replace("<", """").Replace(">", """") + "</from>"
                        Dim Subject As String = "<subject>" + oStore.StoreItem_GetProperty("PR_SUBJECT").Replace("<", """").Replace(">", """").ToString + "</subject>"
                        Dim Size As String = "<size>" + oStore.StoreItem_GetProperty("PR_ME_SIZE").ToString + "</size>"
                        Dim Status As String = "<status>" + oStore.StoreItem_GetProperty("PR_ME_FLAGSTATUS").ToString + "</status>"

                        Dim WrapperEnd As String = "</message>"

                        XMLFile = XMLFile + WrapperStart + ItemId + MessageDate + Attachments + From + Subject + Size + Status + WrapperEnd
                    Loop While (oStore.StoreFolder_FindNextItem() = 1)
                    XMLFile = "<messages>" + XMLFile + "</messages>"
                End If
                APIResult = oStore.StoreFolder_FindClose()
                APIResult = oStore.StoreFolder_Close()
            Else
                Throw New ArgumentException("Invalid Mailbox!")
            End If
        End If
        XMLFile = "<result status=""Success"">" + XMLFile + "</result>"
    Catch ex As Exception
        XMLFile = "<result status=""Err""><reason>" + ex.Message + "</reason></result>"
    End Try
    Return XMLFile
End Function

Private Function fnGetTotalCount(Username As String, Postoffice As String) As String
    Dim XMLFile As String = ""
    Dim c As Integer = 0
    Try
        If Len(Username) <= 0 Or Len(Postoffice) <= 0 Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("Invalid Parameters!")
        Else
            Dim oMailbox As New MailEnable.Administration.Mailbox
            oMailbox.Postoffice = Postoffice
            oMailbox.MailboxName = Username
            oMailbox.Status = 1

            If oMailbox.GetMailbox() = 1 Then
                Dim APIResult As Long
                Dim oStore As New MailEnable.Store
                APIResult = oStore.StoreFolder_Open(Postoffice, Username, "\Inbox", 0, 1)
                If oStore.StoreFolder_FindFirstItem() = 1 Then
                    Do
                        c = c + 1
                    Loop While (oStore.StoreFolder_FindNextItem() = 1)
                    XMLFile = "<count>" + c.ToString + "</count>"
                End If
                APIResult = oStore.StoreFolder_FindClose()
                APIResult = oStore.StoreFolder_Close()
            Else
                Throw New ArgumentException("Invalid Mailbox!")
            End If
        End If
        XMLFile = "<result status=""Success"">" + XMLFile + "</result>"
    Catch ex As Exception
        XMLFile = "<result status=""Err""><reason>" + ex.Message + "</reason></result>"
    End Try
    Return XMLFile
End Function

Private Function fnGetUnreadCount(Username As String, Postoffice As String) As String
    Dim XMLFile As String = ""
    Dim c As Integer = 0
    Try
        If Len(Username) <= 0 Or Len(Postoffice) <= 0 Then
            Throw New ArgumentException("Invalid Parameters!")
        Else
            Dim oMailbox As New MailEnable.Administration.Mailbox
            oMailbox.Postoffice = Postoffice
            oMailbox.MailboxName = Username
            oMailbox.Status = 1

            If oMailbox.GetMailbox() = 1 Then
                Dim APIResult As Long
                Dim oStore As New MailEnable.Store
                APIResult = oStore.StoreFolder_Open(Postoffice, Username, "\Inbox", 0, 1)
                If oStore.StoreFolder_FindFirstItem() = 1 Then
                    Do
                        If oStore.StoreItem_GetProperty("PR_ME_READ").ToString = "0" Or oStore.StoreItem_GetProperty("PR_ME_READ").ToString = "" Then
                            c = c + 1
                        End If
                    Loop While (oStore.StoreFolder_FindNextItem() = 1)
                    XMLFile = "<count>" + c.ToString + "</count>"
                End If
                APIResult = oStore.StoreFolder_FindClose()
                APIResult = oStore.StoreFolder_Close()
            Else
                Throw New ArgumentException("Invalid Mailbox!")
            End If
        End If
        XMLFile = "<result status=""Success"">" + XMLFile + "</result>"
    Catch ex As Exception
        XMLFile = "<result status=""Err""><reason>" + ex.Message + "</reason></result>"
    End Try
    Return XMLFile
End Function

Private Function fnCreateMailAccount(Username As String, Postoffice As String) As String
    Dim XMLFile As String = ""
    Dim MailBoxQuota As Long = 102400
    Try
        If Len(Username) > 0 And Len(Postoffice) > 0 Then

            Dim oPostoffice As New MailEnable.Administration.Postoffice
            Dim oDomain As New MailEnable.Administration.Domain

            oPostoffice.Account = Postoffice
            oPostoffice.Name = Postoffice
            oPostoffice.Host = Postoffice
            oPostoffice.Status = 1
            If oPostoffice.GetPostoffice <> 1 Then
                CreatePostoffice(Postoffice, New Guid().ToString.Substring(20))
            End If

            Dim oLogin As New MailEnable.Administration.Login
            oLogin.Account = Postoffice
            oLogin.LastAttempt = -1
            oLogin.LastSuccessfulLogin = -1
            oLogin.LoginAttempts = -1
            oLogin.Password = ""
            oLogin.Rights = ""
            oLogin.Status = -1
            oLogin.UserName = Username & "@" & Postoffice
            If oLogin.GetLogin <> 1 Then
                oLogin.LastAttempt = 0
                oLogin.LastSuccessfulLogin = 0
                oLogin.LoginAttempts = 0
                oLogin.Password = Right(Guid.NewGuid().ToString, 16)
                oLogin.Rights = "USER"
                oLogin.Status = 1

                'Create Login
                If oLogin.AddLogin = 1 Then

                End If

                oLogin = Nothing

                Dim oMailbox As New MailEnable.Administration.Mailbox
                oMailbox.Postoffice = Postoffice
                oMailbox.MailboxName = Username
                oMailbox.RedirectAddress = ""
                oMailbox.RedirectStatus = 0
                oMailbox.Size = 0
                oMailbox.Limit = MailBoxQuota
                oMailbox.Status = 1

                'Create Mailbox
                If oMailbox.AddMailbox = 1 Then
                    '
                    ' Mailbox was added - What could go wrong!
                    '
                End If

                oMailbox = Nothing
                ' Finally, we need to assign address map(s) for the mailbox

                Dim oAddressMap As New MailEnable.Administration.AddressMap
                oAddressMap.Account = Postoffice
                oAddressMap.DestinationAddress = "[SF:" & Postoffice & "/" & Username & "]"
                oAddressMap.SourceAddress = "[SMTP:" & Username & "@" & Postoffice & "]"
                oAddressMap.Scope = 0
                If oAddressMap.AddAddressMap = 1 Then
                    '
                    ' Address Map was added too - What could go wrong!
                    '
                End If
                oAddressMap = Nothing
                XMLFile = "<result status=""Success""></result>"
            Else
                Throw New ArgumentException("Account already exists!")
            End If
        Else
            Throw New ArgumentException("Invalid Parameters!")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        XMLFile = "<result status=""Err""><reason>" + ex.Message + "</reason></result>"
    End Try
    Return XMLFile
End Function

Function CreatePostoffice(sPostoffice As String, sPassword As String) As String
    Dim oPostOffice As New MailEnable.Administration.Postoffice
    Dim oMailbox As New MailEnable.Administration.Mailbox
    Dim oLogin As New MailEnable.Administration.Login
    Dim lResult As Long
    CreatePostoffice = False
    If Len(sPostoffice) > 0 And Len(sPassword) > 0 Then
        oPostOffice.Account = sPostoffice
        oPostOffice.Name = sPostoffice
        oPostOffice.Status = 1
        lResult = oPostOffice.AddPostoffice
        If (lResult = 1) Then
            oMailbox.Postoffice = sPostoffice
            oMailbox.Limit = -1
            oMailbox.MailboxName = "Postmaster"
            oMailbox.RedirectAddress = ""
            oMailbox.RedirectStatus = 0
            oMailbox.Status = 1
            lResult = oMailbox.AddMailbox
            If (lResult = 1) Then
                oLogin.Account = sPostoffice
                oLogin.Description = "Postmaster Mailbox"
                oLogin.Password = sPassword
                oLogin.Rights = "ADMIN"
                oLogin.Status = 1
                oLogin.UserName = "Postmaster@" & sPostoffice
                lResult = oLogin.AddLogin
                If (lResult = 1) Then
                    CreatePostoffice = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    oPostoffice = Nothing
    oMailbox = Nothing
    oLogin = Nothing
End Function


End Class
```

Though this is not the complete answer, you can start working on it. This way.
Place this ashx code in your MailEnable webmail folder and request from your application.
QueryStringModule is a available to download [here](http://madskristensen.net/post/httpmodule-for-query-string-encryption)
QueryStringModule is used in your application to encrypt http requests and decrypt at MailEnable application.
Allow only your application IP at MailEnable web application for security reasons.

Comment: I've upvoted your answer and comments as a thank you for your afforts. I hope to give it a try as soon as I finish the projects at hand ;) Thank you!